# Detail Text for Tableview in popover in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, popup

I open a PopOverview which contains a table View. It works fine But my cell also contain the detail Text which is not seen in table view cell when i open table view in popOver.

My code is as follow:

```
-(IBAction)btnTableMenu_TouchUpInside:(id)sender{

   ListView *popUp=[[ListView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListView" bundle:nil];



popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popUp];
popoverController.delegate =self;

[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 700)];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(150,25,20,50) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];


}
```

**How can i solve This??**

Comment: go in to your nib and connect UITable Outlet and give propar Delegate  :)

Comment: Can you paste your UItableView Datasource methods here ?

Comment: Can you add the code for -cellForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: @user1673099  Were you ever able to display cell.detailLabel.text?  If so, can you please share the details?  Here is my question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414024/fppopover-cell-detailtextlabel-text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

see user167.. you just need to create new `UITableViewcontroller` for example `DropDwnLevel1TableViewController.h`, `DropDwnLevel1TableViewController.m` and `xib` right.

Now in `DropDwnLevel1TableViewController` Create IBOutlate of `UITableVIew` set one UITableView in to `nib` connect `IBOUTLATE` and set `Delegate` and `dataSource`

Now you can set created `TableViewController` add in to your `UIPopoverViewcontroller` like below method:-

```
-(IBAction)btnTableMenu_TouchUpInside:(id)sender{

  DropDwnLevel1TableViewController *firstViewCtrl = [[DropDwnLevel1TableViewController alloc] init];
        firstViewCtrl.title=@"My tableView";

        UINavigationController *navbar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewCtrl];

        [firstViewCtrl contentSizeForViewInPopover];

        myPopOVer = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navbar];
        [navbar release];

        myPopOVer.delegate = self;
        myPopOVer.popoverContentSize =CGSizeMake(250,200);

        [myPopOVer presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:sender.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];


}
```

**FOR dismiss popOVer**

In you class which declare `popOverViewcontroller` `.m` file `ViewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     // Hear creating NSNotificationCenter for dismiss popover

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(DismissPopOver:)
                                                 name:@"Dismiss"
                                               object:nil];

  [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)DismissPopOver:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [yourPopOVer dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

Now in `DropDwnLevel1TableViewController.m` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
          // hear call NSNotificationCenter who creating in main class
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Dismiss" object:self];

}
```

Comment: Now, My code is working as above. But when i select the row, the popover is not dismiss. Can you help me??

Comment: [yourPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; write this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath Methods.

Comment: but my popover is in different class & my tableview is in different class which i open i popover.

Comment: check my updated answer you need to just Creating `NSNotificationCenter` hope its helps you and you can understand the method or code

Comment: sorry but nothing is happened

Comment: see may be you lil mistack any please check proparly Read my asnwer carefully and follow with intruction because i put my working code that's why

Comment: @jattt.... why are you copying my answer..? any different in your answer.. bro..?

Comment: @Nitin Gohel Let me say it's your answer. I want to just help. my motto is not get point. so don't worry someone already down vote it. By the way you just copy and paste my code into your answer.

Comment: @VinodSingh and Nitin thanks for helping each other out in faced paced moving answers. It's all good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

Add the observer in the class where your `popOverController` view is

your `popOverController` class

**yourPopOverControlle.m**

```
-(void)viewdidLoad{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(removePopover:) name:@"hidePopOver" object:nil];

}
-(void)removePopover:(NSNotification *)notification{
   [yourPopOver  dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

**yourTableViewController.m**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"hidePopOver" object:nil]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To see detailed text label you need create you cell with UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle style;

For example :

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell * cell = nil;
```

```
cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTableCellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
{
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kTableCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
```

```
// configure cell
    cell.textLabel.text = "text label text";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = "detailed text label text";
```

```
return cell;
}
```